# gem added to gemfile and bundle install is run but still am seeing Gem::LoadError: unicorn is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, digital-ocean

Am using mina for deployment. Am having `gem 'mina-unicorn', :require => false` in the Gemfile(I tried replacing the above line with `gem 'unicorn'`) and then I did `bundle install`.

When I run mina deploy --verbose I see `bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/unicorn)
Gem::LoadError: unicorn is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.`

Looks like some problem with the path of the gem files not being set properly.

Here is the console output

```
-----> Loading environment
$ source ~/.bashrc
-----> Loading rbenv
$ export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"
$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"
-----> Creating a temporary build path
$ touch "deploy.lock"
$ mkdir -p "$build_path"
$ cd "$build_path"
-----> Quiet sidekiq (stop accepting new work)
Skip quiet command (no pid file found)
-----> Fetching new git commits
$ (cd "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/scm" && git fetch "https://kkteja@bitbucket.org/kkteja/salesforce_casts.git" "master:master" --force)
-----> Using git branch 'master'
$ git clone "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/scm" . --recursive --branch "master"
Cloning into '.'...
done.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
-----> Using this git commit

$ git rev-parse HEAD > .mina_git_revision
$ git --no-pager log --format='%aN (%h):%n> %s' -n 1
Krishna Teja (ec42bcc):
> added about me
$ rm -rf .git

-----> Symlinking shared paths
$ mkdir -p "./config"
$ mkdir -p "."
$ rm -rf "./config/database.yml"
$ ln -s "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/config/database.yml" "./config/database.yml"
$ rm -rf "./config/secrets.yml"
$ ln -s "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/config/secrets.yml" "./config/secrets.yml"
$ rm -rf "./log"
$ ln -s "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/log" "./log"
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
$ mkdir -p "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle"
$ mkdir -p "./vendor"
$ ln -s "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle" "./vendor/bundle"
$ bundle install --without development:test --path "./vendor/bundle" --deployment
Using rake 11.1.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
Using arel 6.0.3
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using ionicons-rails 2.0.0
Using multi_json 1.12.0
Using pg 0.18.4
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.2
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mime-types 3.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using sprockets 3.6.0
Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activemerchant 1.58.0
Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
Using jbuilder 2.4.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using activejob 4.2.5.1
Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
Using actionview 4.2.5.1
Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
Using railties 4.2.5.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using responders 2.1.1
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using tinymce-rails 4.3.12
Using rails 4.2.5.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using devise 3.5.6
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 61 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
-----> DB migrations unchanged; skipping DB migration
-----> Skipping asset precompilation
$ mkdir -p "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/$build_path/public/assets"
$ cp -R "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/public/assets/." "/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/$build_path/public/assets"
-----> Deploy finished
-----> Building
-----> Moving build to releases/8
$ mv "$build_path" "$release_path"
$ cd "$release_path"
-----> Build finished
-----> Launching
-----> Updating the current symlink
$ ln -nfs "$release_path" "current"
-----> Launching
$ cd "current"
-----> Starting Unicorn...
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/unicorn)
Gem::LoadError: unicorn is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:322:in `block in replace_gem'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/unicorn:22:in `<top (required)>'
-----> Done. Deployed v8
Connection to 139.59.9.195 closed.
       Elapsed time: 9.00 seconds
```

When I run `gem which unicorn` I see this
`/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb`

This is what `gem env` gives

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.2 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/deployer/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /home/deployer/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin
     - /home/deployer/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/deployer/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin
     - /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin
```

This is the `config/deploy.rb` file

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rbenv'  # for rbenv support. (http://rbenv.org)
# require 'mina/rvm'    # for rvm support. (http://rvm.io)
require 'mina_sidekiq/tasks'
require 'mina/unicorn'
# Basic settings:
#   domain       - The hostname to SSH to.
#   deploy_to    - Path to deploy into.
#   repository   - Git repo to clone from. (needed by mina/git)
#   branch       - Branch name to deploy. (needed by mina/git)

set :domain, '139.59.9.195'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deployer/salesforcecasts'
set :repository, 'https://kkteja@bitbucket.org/kkteja/salesforce_casts.git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :user, 'deployer'
set :forward_agent, true
set :port, '22'
set :unicorn_pid, "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
set :term_mode, nil
# For system-wide RVM install.
#   set :rvm_path, '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm'

# Manually create these paths in shared/ (eg: shared/config/database.yml) in your server.
# They will be linked in the 'deploy:link_shared_paths' step.
set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'log']

# Optional settings:
#   set :user, 'foobar'    # Username in the server to SSH to.
#   set :port, '30000'     # SSH port number.
#   set :forward_agent, true     # SSH forward_agent.

# This task is the environment that is loaded for most commands, such as
# `mina deploy` or `mina rake`.
task :environment do
  # If you're using rbenv, use this to load the rbenv environment.
  # Be sure to commit your .ruby-version or .rbenv-version to your repository.
  queue %{
        echo "-----> Loading environment"
        #{echo_cmd %[source ~/.bashrc]}
  }
  invoke :'rbenv:load'

  # For those using RVM, use this to load an RVM version@gemset.
  # invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-1.9.3-p125@default]'
end

# Put any custom mkdir's in here for when `mina setup` is ran.
# For Rails apps, we'll make some of the shared paths that are shared between
# all releases.
task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"]
  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit '#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml' and 'secrets.yml'."]
  # sidekiq needs a place to store its pid file and log file
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids/"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids"]

  if repository
    repo_host = repository.split(%r{@|://}).last.split(%r{:|\/}).first
    repo_port = /:([0-9]+)/.match(repository) && /:([0-9]+)/.match(repository)[1] || '22'

    queue %[
      if ! ssh-keygen -H  -F #{repo_host} &>/dev/null; then
        ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p #{repo_port} -H #{repo_host} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      fi
    ]
  end
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  to :before_hook do
    # Put things to run locally before ssh
  end
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'sidekiq:quiet'
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    #invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    to :launch do
     # queue "mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/"
     #queue "touch #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
     #invoke :'sidekiq:restart'
     invoke :'unicorn:restart'
    end
  end
end
```

This is `config/unicorn.rb`

```
# set path to application
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
working_directory app_dir


# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Logging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/pids/unicorn.pid"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{app_dir}/Gemfile"
end
```

This is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
#gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'mina'
gem 'mina-sidekiq', :require => false
gem 'mina-unicorn', :require => false
gem 'devise'
gem 'ionicons-rails'
gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'tinymce-rails'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
#gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'faker'
end
 gem 'rails_12factor'

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

**UPDATE**

```
$ bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production -C /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/config/sidekiq.yml -c 25 -i 0 -P /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid -L /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/log/sidekiq.log
-----> Starting Unicorn...
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn)
ArgumentError: directory for pid=/home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/shared/pids/unicorn.pid not writable
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:88:in `block in reload'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:84:in `each'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:84:in `reload'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:65:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `new'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /home/deployer/salesforcecasts/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
-----> Done. Deployed v6
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Could you add the Gemfile to the question's description?

Comment: added the gemfile @etagwerker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mina-unicorn` doesn't have `unicorn` dependency according to its [gemspec](https://github.com/scarfacedeb/mina-unicorn/blob/ecc4f3307ca70006a8e109a84e0b1259f8063922/mina-unicorn.gemspec), you have to add it explicitly in your Gemfile

```
gem 'mina-unicorn', :require => false
gem 'unicorn'
```

Also, based on your `bundle install` output, you could tell that unicorn was not installed.

```
Using rake 11.1.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
Using arel 6.0.3
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using ionicons-rails 2.0.0
Using multi_json 1.12.0
Using pg 0.18.4
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.2
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mime-types 3.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using sprockets 3.6.0
Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activemerchant 1.58.0
Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
Using jbuilder 2.4.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using activejob 4.2.5.1
Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
Using actionview 4.2.5.1
Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
Using railties 4.2.5.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using responders 2.1.1
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using tinymce-rails 4.3.12
Using rails 4.2.5.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using devise 3.5.6
```

UPDATE:

What mina does is:

Fetch the codebase from remote repository you specified in you `config/deploy.rb`, which is https://kkteja@bitbucket.org/kkteja/salesforce_casts.git, and from the file https://bitbucket.org/kkteja/salesforce_casts/src/ec42bcc304fb581f5b7a0a61b9c073f66b0dffac/Gemfile?fileviewer=file-view-default you could see, `unicorn` is not it.

Although you added it in your Gemfile, if you don't commit the changes to bitbucket, it won't affect mina deploy.

Actually, you don't have to clone the repo to digital ocean manually, all the deploy stuff could be done on your own machine.

UPDATE:

Make sure your pid file and directory is writable for your `deployer` user, like the log said.

Comment: I second that. I did a couple of trail runs having both mins-unicorn and unicorn in the gem file, I was getting the same error. However I will try to recheck it once again. Any pointer why unicorn is not installed even if it's included in gem file and I had explicitly run gem install unicorn also.

Comment: When you added `unicorn` to Gemfile, did you commit and push the changes to remote repository?

Comment: So the approach am following is clone the repo to digital ocean droplet, created the 'config/unicorn.rb file', and then I ran 'mina init' and 'mina setup' and 'mina deploy'. So I have not configured the droplet to any repository, rather am cloning the repo and configuring it. Also to make sure I removed the Gemfile.lock and ran 'bundle install'

Comment: Oops I didn't know that. I have one last question Larry, after that I will do the changes you suggested and will check. The app folder name is salesforcecasts where as the git repo name is salesforce_casts.git. Not having the folder name same as the git repo name, does it effect anything?

Comment: No, it does not. Whatever your folder is, it doesn't matter. mina will clone your repository to your "#{deploy_to}/scm" directory, you could confirm that from the log output. And the bundle stuff also happens in your `deploy_to` directory. (hint: don't do anything in your deploy_to dir unless putting the shared yml files, and let mina do all the other stuff)

Comment: Sure Larry will try committing the code to repo and will check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115086/discussion-between-krishna-teja-karnam-and-larry-lv).